# Can I add a relative path to directory to add a repository to Trac?

Tags: trac

I am able to add a absolute path directory for the trac repository. When I give a relative path, It is not accepting it. Is there any config which I am missing for this in Trac?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Only absolute paths are [allowed](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.0.6/trac/versioncontrol/admin.py?marks=368-371#L364). I've considered looking into whether this restriction can be removed. What would your path be relative to? The environment directory?

Comment: If I have Trac on one server and subversion repositories on another version. Will I be able to integrate them (Eg: My source code is on  https://172.206.154.101/SVN_Projects/Project1 and Trac is installed on: http://172.206.154.102/trac/ How will I add repositories to trac)

Comment: Remote subversion repositories are [not supported](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/493). A workaround that I've seen successfully employed is to mirror a read-only copy of the Subversion repository on the server that hosts Trac and use [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnsync.html) to keep them synchronized.

Comment: Since git is a distributed version control system, just making a clone of the repository gives you a "synchronized" instance. I'm not sure of the best way to trigger the update of the sync'ed repository, but I'm sure you can find dedicated threads on SO about that. Maybe with Git hooks?